# navigating different pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a page index.html.Suppose I have other page `index2.html`.
By clicking on a certain link in index.html I want to move to a certain div id in `index2.html`.Is that possible using css or js?

index.html has following link:

```
<a href="index2.html #div2"> <!--code i am looking for-->
```

index2.html has following content

```
<div id="div1" style="height:1000px;width:100%"></div>
<div id="div2" style="height:400px;width:100%"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. This is possible. Infact, you have have almost done it right. change from

```
<a href="index2.html #div2">
```

to

```
<a href="index2.html#div2">
```

Means there should be no space between index2.html and #div2.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes just remove the space you put between the page and the `div id`

```
<a href="index2.html #div2"> <!--code i am looking for-->
```

Change to

```
 <a href="index2.html#div2"> <!--code you need-->
```

Hope you get how this works